# How can i render my function in React ? I can't render this

Tags: reactjs

Function holding the ternary syntax and I can't able to render the content of the `newElement` function.

Used variables:

`test1 = 1;`
`IstestString = true;`

Render functions:

```
newElement = () => this.test1 === 1
  ? <h1>test is one</h1>
  : <h1>test is not one </h1>;

render() {
  return (
     <div className='App'> 
       <p style={style}>{this.newElement}</p>    
     </div>
  );
}
```

Someone can help me to find the problem here, please?

Comment: {this.newElement()}

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from your function in order to render `jsx`

Try something like below:-

```
newElement = () => {
 return (
   this.test1 === 1 ? 
     <h1> test is one</h1> : <h1>test is not one </h1>
   )
 }

render() {
  return (
     <div className='App'> 
     <p style={style}>{this.newElement()}</p>    // add brackets here to call function
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return a JSX element and avoid using render in a *normal* component function.

```
let NewElement = () => {
  return (
      <p style={{ display: "block" }}>
        {true ? <h1>test is one</h1> : <h1>test is not one </h1>}
      </p>
  );
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>A New Element</h1>
      <NewElement />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a `return` value.

Also, be careful with your comparison. There's a difference between `==` and `===`. The first one compares value but not type. The second one compares both value and type. Just look it up on google.

Note: You can keep your `<p></p>`, just for clarity's sake I excluded it (because technically it's not necessary but I don't know what you're trying to display)

```js
newElement = () => {
let check = this.test1===1 ? <h1> test is one</h1> : <h1>test is not one</h1>
return check;
 }

render() {
  return (
     <div className='App'> 
        {this.newElement()}  
     </div>
  );
}
```